# Print post category name from a custom post type wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, php

I would like to call the category name of my custom post type in the post but I can not get just the name of it printed follow my code:

functions

```
<?php
    add_action('init', 'type_post_representantes');

    function type_post_representantes() { 
        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x('Representantes', 'post type general name'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Representantes', 'post type singular name'),
            'add_new' => _x('Adicionar Novo', 'Novo item'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Novo Item'),
            'edit_item' => __(' Item'),
            'new_item' => __('Novo Item'),
            'view_item' => __('Ver Item'),
            'search_items' => __('Procurar Itens'),
            'not_found' =>  __('Nenhum registro encontrado'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nenhum registro encontrado na lixeira'),
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'menu_name' => 'Representantes'
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'public_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,           
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => null,
            'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'revisions', 'trackbacks')
          );

register_post_type( 'representantes' , $args );
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
?>
<?php
register_taxonomy(
"categorias", 
      "representantes", 
      array(            
        "label" => "Categorias", 
            "singular_label" => "Categoria", 
            "rewrite" => true,
            "hierarchical" => true
)
);
?>

html:

<?php 
$newsArgs = array( 'post_type' => 'representantes', 'posts_per_page' => 30);                   

      $newsLoop = new WP_Query( $newsArgs );                  

      while ( $newsLoop->have_posts() ) : $newsLoop->the_post();              ?>
           <div class="representantes" style="display:block !important;"><!---blocos--->
           <?php the_taxonomies(array('template' => '% %l')); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
           </div><!--FINAL BLOCO-->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the flush_rewrite_rules function like that read the docs https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules#Usage

In the param "template" you have an error:

```
<?php the_taxonomies(array('template' => '% %l')); ?>

<?php the_taxonomies(array('template' => '%s %l')); ?>
```

If you are using the default value just call the function without any params

**Edit:** I use this code when I want just one term from a custom taxonomy:

```
// note the [0] beacuse the wp_get_post_terms returns all the terms from the post
$tc = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'categorias');
if( !is_wp_error($tc) && !empty($tc) ){
    $categoria_name = $tc[0]->name;
    $categoria_slug = $tc[0]->slug;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new with programming, I'm looking for the name of the post category in my custom post type..how to give me the way I could not understand the codex

Comment: I edited my answer with an example of how I do it.

Comment: did not work before the category name appeared with the link now nothing appears

Comment: Man you really need to read some php tutorials, the values are saving in variables so you can manipulate them ej: echo $categoria_name; will display the term name...